# Access 2016: Displaying name instead of ID in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I am very new to Access and I am having an issue which I can't seem to solve based on my limited knowledge.

I have a table named T_Database where I have all my entries and information. Notably, with the fields Number, Date, Region, and id_fournisseur. (id_fournisseur is translated to id_supplier).

A second table named T_fournisseur contains id_fournisseur as well as Fournisseurs (Suppliers).

Now, I created a form F_multicriteres to consult the data as other users will be viewing it. This form has the purpose of filtering the database according to certain filters, ie filter by date and supplier, etc. The form F_multicriteres opens a second form once the user press on the button "search". This second form is named F_infos where the results of the search are shown.
I am also using the query R_infos, which has the following relation: [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prk8L.png)

My issue is that the form F_infos shows the fournisseur(supplier) as the ID instead of its name (see image below, fourth column).
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY3kH.png)

Here are the solutions and ideas I have tried when looking at similar threads online:

1. Using DLookup
   `=DLookup("Fournisseurs", "T_fournisseur", "id_fournisseur = '" & [id_fournisseur] & "'")`
2. Using SQL code to Insert Join the two id_fournisseur

```
SELECT T_Database.numero, T_Database.date, T_Database.region, T_Database.categorie, T_Database.organisme, T_fournisseur.Fournisseurs
FROM T_Database
INNER JOIN T_fournisseur ON T_Database.id_fournisseur = T_fournisseur.id_fournisseur
```

3. Change my textbox to a combobox
4. Change the Record Source

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    strSQL = "SELECT Fournisseurs FROM T_fournisseur WHERE id_fournisseur = " & Me.Controls("id_fournisseur").Value
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Me.Txt_Fournisseurs.Value = rs.Fields("Fournisseurs").Value
    Else
        Me.Txt_Fournisseurs.Value = ""
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

5. Creating a query having the fields of T_Database and the field Fournisseurs of T_fournisseur

After more research, I learned that using the Lookup Wizard would be the least smart move so I did not try to implement this solution as it plays with the normalization.

I am clueless on what to do to make it work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if more screenshots are needed to clarify my issue.

Comment: As your query only pulls field `Fournisseurs`, there is no way it could pass the Id. So, something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works for me!

I am using the following;

```
=RechDom("[Fournisseurs]";"[T_fournisseur]";"[id_fournisseur] = " & [id_fournisseur])
```

Where RechDom is translated to DLookUp. I have also put the property Enabled to 'No' as well as the property Locked to 'Yes'.

Here is the post which helped https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/834663-how-display-text-text-box-whose-source-id-number.